# How to resovle rename exception in Pymongo map reduce

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, reduce

I have a map reduce that runs every hour on my server as a cronjob.  I come across an error that prevents the map reduce from completing.  This typically happens when I run the map reduce script locally it collides at the same time with the map reduce on the server.  There has also been some cases where I run it locally at a separate time as the server job when the error occurs.  The error is

```
errmsg: "exception: rename failed: { errmsg: "exception: target namespace exists", code: 10027, ok: 0.0 }", code: 10076, ok: 0.0 }
```

This error prevents me from deleting the collection as well running my script to write over the current reduced collection.  Do you know how to prevent this from occurring or resolve the issue so that I can drop the collection

this is the command i use to run the map reduce

```
articles.map_reduce(map, reduce, "articleTrending", query=queryFilter)
```

Comment: So what is your point? Are you "testing"? If so then use a different output collection, or better yet run your tests on a totally different machine. From what you are saying this job or something else is working on the collection when you try to run it. So either schedule your two different jobs ( don't know you would have them ) to not collide or just don't run on the same targets.

Comment: job collision is not the only case that where I get the error

Comment: So what do you expect people to do about it based on the information you have given? Clearly you are trying to replace a collection at the same time as something else is using it. So the reasoning here is don't use the same namespace in more than one place.

Comment: Was curious if someone knows why this error would come up. And why mongo does not even allow me to drop the collection. I don't want to have to switch the name in every file I reference this collection. Don't you think this behavior is a bit bizarre of a database? I found another source where they were having the same issue but no one had a resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing "articleTrending" as the "out" parameter, it sounds like you want to "replace" that collection. So you can do this instead:

```
articles.map_reduce(map, reduce, {"replace": "articleTrending"}, query=queryFilter)
```

There are a number of options for how to deal with mapReduce output. The official MongoDB docs for "out" [are here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-out-cmd). There are some [python examples here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/examples/aggregation.html#advanced-map-reduce).

Comment: i've taken this measure as an extra precaution along with lightening the load on my map reduce by applying a smaller limit on the query. since then, i have not run into the issue.  if anyone knows why the behavior above occurs, please share